# angular seed and express-generator on github

Tags: angularjs, git

I am working on express-angular app (my IDE is Webstorm), and used express-generator to create directory structure (Webstorm project1-server):

```
PROJECT1-server
\bin
\node-modules
\public
\routes
\views
app.js
package.json
```

I created github repository with the above. Now I Also used angular seed to create seperate directory structure (Webstorm project2-client), including \app folder.

```
PROJECT2-client
\app
\e2e-tests
bower.json
karma.conf.js
package.json
```

Now I don't know how to add that /app folder to github repository ? I want this to be one repository on github, but two projects in my Webstorm: server and client part, specially because client is using dev server locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your repository root directory is the server project directory.

- Create a new folder named server and move the first project files there
- Make sure .gitignore and .gitattributes stays in the root directory
- Create a new folder name client and move the second project files there
- Commit and push